Unexpected horizontal margins in ListTile
In this screenshot, I've got a ListView with three empty ListTiles. However, in the iOS version, the ListTiles have large horizontal margins (shown in purple), which I don't want. I've tried adding negative content padding, but nothing is working. How do I get rid of them? Thanks.

class TasksPane extends StatelessWidget with WatchItMixin {
  const TasksPane({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = watchIt<RpmTodoController>();
    final log = Logger(graphicPrinter);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: controller.all,
              icon: const FaIcon(Icons.filter_list_off),
              tooltip: 'View all tasks',
              iconSize: 18.0,
              // color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: controller.soon,
              icon: const FaIcon(Icons.timer),
              tooltip: 'View tasks for this week',
              iconSize: 18.0,
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: controller.urgent,
              icon: const FaIcon(Icons.priority_high),
              tooltip: 'View tasks for this week',
              iconSize: 18.0,
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: controller.today,
              icon: const FaIcon(Icons.today),
              tooltip: 'View urgent tasks',
              iconSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: controller.todos.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final todo = controller.todos[index];
                const child = ListTile();

                return Draggable<CVEvent>(
                    data: todo,
                    feedback: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(const Size(500, 60)),
                      child: const Material(
                        child: Opacity(
                          opacity: 0.75,
                          child: child,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    childWhenDragging:
                        const Opacity(opacity: 0.5, child: child),
                    onDragEnd: (x) =>
                        log.i('$todo Drag ended with ${x.wasAccepted}'),
                    child: child);
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


try adding the visualDensity: VisualDensity.minimumDensity, in the ListTile

Thanks, but that only affects the layout of the ListTile children. It appears to have no effect on the extra padding.

Ok then apply zero padding to the ListView.builder widget after itemCount: controller.todos.length, add padding: EdgeInsets.zero,.
